# WatchOS and when to put methods on the main thread

Tags: multithreading, watchkit

It seems like for WatchOS extensions, it is more often the case where code needs to be explicitly placed on the main thread, as opposed to explicitly put in the background or another queue as in IOS. What activities need to be explicitly put on the main thread in WatchOS extensions? What I have seen is that this is being done when either updating the user interface or when  changing the state of a workout with HealthKit.

For example, before I update the label values on my watchOS interface view controller I am calling the main queue:

```
func locationUpdate(locationDict: [String:AnyObject]) {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if let first = locationDict["firstValue"] as? String {
        self.firstValue.setText(first)
    }
    if let second = locationDict["second"] as? String {
        self.secondValue.setText(second)
    }
    }
```

Is this required? I would not do this in iOS.  Are there other common cases? Is there a good reference regarding special main queue considerations for WatchOS?

Comment: I woulddo this in iOS. Fixed several bugs for me. The last one yesterday where a problem for some weird timing reasons only occured on an iPhone 4s but not on newer iPhones.